# How to Print all the rows in a table instead of one using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a table with five rows, and i wrote a php code to print all the rows in the table. 
But unfortunately im missing somecode which actually triggers the continuity in getting data instead of one row from table..

My code as follows:

```
<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM useraddmoneyhistory ORDER BY date DESC";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2); 
if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    $index = 0; 
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $index++; 
        ?>                    
        <table class="table table-hover" >
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
                <th>Earlier Balance</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>

            <tr >
                <td><?php echo ($row2["id"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($row2["mobile"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($row2["preamount"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($row2["amount"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($row2["amountdis"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($row2["date"]); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Any Help is Greatly Appreciated...

Comment: Put your HTML in your loop. Otherwise you only ever get the last row.

Comment: where is your closing brace?

Comment: i have them, but i haven't mentioned them in the question..

Comment: @JohnConde how do you mean by putting them in loop. like should i rearrange the php code?

Comment: enclose only <tr> ...</tr> inside while loop not the whole table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put html in loop , in your code `while` and `if` statement dose not closed.

```
<table class="table table-hover" >
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
<th>Earlier Balance</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Discount</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>

<?php
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?> 
    ... HTML 'tr' CODE ...
<?php

} // close while
  $result->free();
} //close if
print "</tr></table>";
?>
```